# Starting point for a collaboratively developed golfing language interpreted in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

Over on Code Golf, we've decided, for once, to write some readable code! However, we're obviously not very good at that, so we need your help to make it even better.

I've proposed [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16047/66833) challenge on PPCG, which requires an interpreter for a new golfing language, written in Python 3.4. I've finished the base file, but, as this will be collaborated on by many users, I need to make sure it's readable, understandable and, well, *not golfed*.

The basic interpreter included a collection of different memory models, as to not restrict modifications, such as a tape (à la [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck)), or a stack, similar to [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), and also includes the basis of commands needed to perform the tasks in the linked challenge.

Unfortunately, it is sparse when it comes to comments, and in addition to feedback on how the code is written, I'd appreciate feedback or suggestions on the level of commenting needed, ranging from *I can barely understand what this is doing, fill it all with comments* to *Pepper a few throughout, near the more complicated parts*. The code is as follows:

```python
import argparse
import collections
import sys

# === Constants === #

inf = float('inf')
nan = float('nan')

digits = str.maketrans('⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉', '01234567890123456789')

code_page  = '''ÀÁÂÄÆÃÅĀĄ\t\nĆČÇĎÐÈÉÊËĒĖĚĘÌÍÎÏĪĮĹĽ'''
code_page += ''' !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¶'''
code_page += '''ŁŃŇÑŊÒÓÔÖŒÕØŌŔŘŚŠŤŦÙÚÛÜŮŪŴÝŶŸŹŽŻàáâäæãåāąćčçďðèéêëēėěęìíîïīįĺľłńňñŋòóôöœøōõŕřßśšťŧùúûüůūŵýŷÿźžż◊'''
code_page += '''ΑΆΒΓΔΕΈΖΗΉΘΙΊΚΛΜΝΞΟΌΠΡΣΤΥΎΦΧΨΩΏ'''

code_page += '''αάβγδεέζηήθιίΐκλμνξοόπσςτυύΰφχψωώ'''
code_page += '''ǴḰḾṔẂǵḱḿṕẃḂḞĠḢṀȮṖṠṪẊḃḟġḣṁȯṗṡṫẋ§ĂĞĬŎŬĴăğĭŏŭĵªº‹›'''
code_page += '''ƁƇƊƑƓƘⱮƝƤƬƲȤɓƈɗƒɠɦƙɱɲƥʠɼʂƭʋȥ©®ıȷ'''
code_page += '''ЉЊЕРТЗУИОПШАСДФГХЈКЛЧЋЅЏЦВБНМЂЖљњертзуиопшасдфгхјклчћѕџцвбнмђжÞþ'''
code_page += '''†∂∆≈≠√∈∉∌∋∩∪¬∧∨⊕¤₽¥£¢€₩‰¿¡⁇⁈‼⁉‽⸘…°•”“„’‘≤«·»≥ᴇ∞¦×⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾÷₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎'''

# === Memory models === #

class Model:
    def is_tape(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ == 'Tape'

    def is_stack(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ == 'Stack'

    def is_grid(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ == 'Grid'

    def is_register(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ == 'Register'

    def is_deque(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ == 'Deque'

class Stack(Model):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.stack = list(values)

    def push(self, *values):
        for value in values:
            self.stack.append(value)

    def pop(self, index = -1):
        return self.stack.pop(index)

    def peek(self, index = -1):
        return self.stack[index % len(self.stack)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Stack({})'.format(self.stack)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stack)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.stack)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.stack[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.stack[index] = value

class Tape(Model):
    def __init__(self, size = inf, wrap = True):
        self.size = size
        self.wrap = wrap
        self.tape = [0]
        self.index = 0
        if size != inf:
            self.tape = [0] * size

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.size == inf:
            return 'Tape([ … ])'

        final = 'Tape(['
        for i, val in enumerate(self.tape):
            val = str(val)
            if i == self.index:
                final += '{' + val + '}'
            else:
                final += val
            final += ' '
        final += '])'
        return final

    def __str__(self):
        if self.size == inf:
            if len(self.tape):
                template = '[ … {} … ]'
                final = ''
                for i, val in enumerate(self.tape):
                    val = str(val)
                    if i == self.index:
                        final += '{' + val + '}'
                    else:
                        final += val
                    final += ' '
                return template.format(final[:-1])

            else:
                return '[ … ]'
        else:
            final = '['
            for i, val in enumerate(self.tape):
                val = str(val)
                if i == self.index:
                    final += '{' + val + '}'
                else:
                    final += val
                final += ' '
            final = final.strip() + ']'
        return final

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.tape)

    @property
    def cell(self):
        return self.tape[self.index]

    def write_cell(self, value):
        self.tape[self.index] = value

    def move_right(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.size != inf:
            if self.wrap:
                self.index %= self.size
        else:
            while self.index >= len(self.tape):
                self.tape.append(0)

    def move_left(self):
        self.index -= 1
        if self.size != inf:
            if self.wrap and self.index < 0:
                self.index = self.size - 1
            elif not self.wrap and self.index < 0:
                raise IndexError

        else:
            if self.index < 0:
                self.tape.insert(0, 0)
                self.index = 0

class Grid(Model):
    def __init__(self, xlen = inf, ylen = inf, xwrap = True, ywrap = True):
        self.xlen = xlen
        self.ylen = ylen
        self.xwrap = xwrap
        self.ywrap = ywrap
        self.xindex = 0
        self.yindex = 0
        self.grid = []
        self.pointer_value = 0

        if xlen != inf:
            if ylen != inf:
                for _ in range(ylen):
                    self.grid.append([0] * xlen)
            else:
                self.grid.append([0] * xlen)
        else:
            if ylen != inf:
                for _ in range(ylen):
                    self.grid.append([0])
            else:
                for _ in range(10):
                    self.grid.append([0] * 10)

    def __repr__(self):
        final = ''

        if self.xlen == inf:
            if self.ylen == inf:
                final = '[ … …\n ⋮ ⋮ ]'
            else:
                final = ''
                for line in self.grid:
                    final += ' ' + str(line) \
                             .replace(',', '') \
                             .replace('[', '') \
                             .replace(']', '') + ' …\n'
                final = '[' + final[1:-1] + ']'
        else:
            if self.ylen == inf:
                final = '[' + ('⋮ ' * int(len(self.grid[0]) * 4/5)) + '\n'
                for line in self.grid:
                    final += ' ' + str(line) \
                             .replace(',', '') \
                             .replace('[', '') \
                             .replace(']', '') + '\n'
                final += ' ' + ('⋮ ' * int(len(self.grid[0]) * 4/5)) + ']'
            else:
                final = ''
                for line in self.grid:
                    final += ' ' + str(line) \
                             .replace(',', '') \
                             .replace('[', '') \
                             .replace(']', '') + '\n'
                final = '[' + final[1:-1] + ']'

        return final

    def __str__(self):
        array = list(map(lambda a: list(map(str, a)), self.grid))
        max_row_length = max(map(len, array))

        for index, row in enumerate(array):
            while len(row) < max_row_length:
                row.append('0')
            array[index] = row

        pad = max(max(map(len, a)) for a in array) + 1
        final = ''
        for row in array:
            for element in row:
                element = element.rjust(pad)
                final += element
            final += '\n'
        return final + '<> {} <> {}'.format(self.xindex, self.yindex)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(strip(flatten(self.grid), 0))

    @property
    def cell(self):
        return self.grid[self.yindex][self.xindex]

    def write_cell(self, value):
        self.grid[self.yindex][self.xindex] = value

    def write_pointer(self):
        self.pointer_value = self.cell

    def move_right(self):
        self.xindex += 1
        if self.xlen == inf:
            self.grid[self.yindex].append(0)
        else:
            if self.xwrap:
                self.xindex %= self.xlen

    def move_left(self):
        self.xindex -= 1
        if self.xlen == inf and self.xindex < 0:
            self.grid[self.yindex].insert(0, 0)
            self.xindex = 0
        else:
            if self.xindex < 0 and self.xwrap:
                self.xindex = self.xlen - abs(self.xindex)
            elif self.xindex < 0 and not self.xwrap:
                self.xindex = self.xlen + 1

    def move_down(self):
        self.yindex += 1
        if self.ylen == inf:
            if self.xlen != inf:
                self.grid.append([0] * self.xlen)
            else:
                self.grid.append([0])
        else:
            if self.ywrap:
                self.yindex %= self.ylen

    def move_up(self):
        self.yindex -= 1
        if self.ylen == inf and self.yindex < 0:
            self.grid[self.xindex].insert(0, 0)
            self.yindex = 0
        else:
            if self.yindex < 0 and self.ywrap:
                self.yindex = self.ylen - abs(self.yindex)
            elif self.yindex < 0 and not self.ywrap:
                self.yindex = self.ylen + 1

class Register(Model, int):
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Register({})'.format(self.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class Deque(Model, collections.deque):
    def __repr__(self):
        rep = super().__repr__()[5:]
        return 'Deque' + rep

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__repr__()[6:-1]

    push = collections.deque.append

def current_value(model):
    if model.is_tape() or model.is_grid():
        return model.cell
    if model.is_stack() or model.is_deque():
        return model.pop()
    if model.is_register():
        return model.value
    return False

def identity(value):
    return value

def overload(stack_cmd = identity, tape_cmd = identity, grid_cmd = identity,
             register_cmd = identity, deque_cmd = identity, all_cmd = None):

    def inner(model):
        if all_cmd is not None:
            return all_cmd(model)

        if model.is_stack():
            return stack_cmd(model)

        if model.is_tape():
            return tape_cmd(model)

        if model.is_grid():
            return grid_cmd(model)

        if model.is_register():
            return register_cmd(model)

        return deque_cmd(model)

    return inner

def make_nilad(value, model):
    value = eval(value)

    if model.is_tape() or model.is_grid():
        model.write_cell(value)

    if model.is_stack():
        model.push(value)

    if model.is_deque():
        model.append(value)

    if model.is_register():
        model.value = value

# === Functions === #

# = Stack Commands = #

def add(stack):
    stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop())

def subtract(stack):
    stack.push(stack.pop() - stack.pop())

def multiply(stack):
    stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop())

def divide(stack):
    stack.push(stack.pop() / stack.pop())

def modulo(stack):
    stack.push(stack.pop() % stack.pop())

def swap(array):
    array[-2], array[-1] = array[-1], array[-2]

def reverse(stack):
    if hasattr(stack.peek(), '__iter__'):
        stack.push(stack.pop()[::-1])
    else:
        stack.stack = stack.stack[::-1]

def product(array):
    total = 1
    for element in array:
        total *= element
    return total

def flatten(array):
    flat = []
    if type(array) == list:
        for item in array:
            flat += flatten(item)
    else:
        flat.append(array)
    return flat

def strip(array, trim):
    final = []
    for value in array:
        if value != trim or final:
            final.append(value)

    array = final[::-1]
    final = []

    for value in array:
        if value != trim or final:
            final.append(value)

    return final[::-1]

def rotate(stack):
    a = stack.pop()
    b = stack.pop()
    c = stack.pop()
    stack.push(a, c, b)

# = Tape / Grid Commands = #

def increment_cell(tape_grid):
    tape_grid.write_cell(tape_grid.cell + 1)

def decrement_cell(tape_grid):
    tape_grid.write_cell(tape_grid.cell - 1)

def write_grid_pointer(grid):
    grid.pointer_value

def getchar():
    ret = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if ret:
        return ret
    return chr(0)

def getinput():
    try:
        inputted = input()
    except:
        return ''
    try:
        return eval(inputted)
    except:
        return inputted

# === Operators === #

def while_loop(code):
    def while_inner(model, used):
        while current_value(model):
            model = interpret(code, model, used)
    return while_inner

def if_statement(code):
    def if_inner(model, used):
        else_, if_ = list(map(lambda a: a[::-1], code[::-1].split('}', 1)))
        if current_value(model):
            model = interpret(if_, model, used)
        else:
            model = interpret(else_, model, used)
    return if_inner

# === Command lookups === #

memories = {

    '#': (0, Tape),
    '$': (0, Stack),
    'G': (0, Grid),
    'D': (0, Deque),
    'S': (1, Register),

    'À': (2, lambda size, wrap: Tape(size, wrap)),
    'Á': (1, lambda size: Tape(size, wrap = True)),
    'Â': (1, lambda size: Tape(size, wrap = False)),
    'Ä': (1, lambda wrap: Tape(wrap = wrap)),

    'Ǵ': (4, lambda xlen, ylen, xwrap, ywrap: Grid(xlen, ylen, xwrap, ywrap)),

}

functions = {

    '+': overload(
            stack_cmd = add,
            deque_cmd = add,
            tape_cmd = increment_cell,
            grid_cmd = increment_cell,
        ),

    '-': overload(
            stack_cmd = subtract,
            deque_cmd = subtract,
            tape_cmd = decrement_cell,
            grid_cmd = decrement_cell,
        ),

    '%': overload(
            stack_cmd = modulo,
            deque_cmd = modulo,
        ),

    ':': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.push(stack.peek()),
            deque_cmd = lambda deque: deque.append(deque[-1]),
        ),

    ';': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.pop(),
            deque_cmd = lambda deque: deque.pop(),
            tape_cmd = lambda tape: tape.write_cell(0),
            grid_cmd = lambda grid: grid.write_cell(0),
        ),

    '<': overload(
            tape_cmd = Tape.move_left,
            grid_cmd = Grid.move_left,
        ),

    '=': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.push(stack.pop() == stack.pop()),
            grid_cmd = Grid.move_down,
        ),

    '>': overload(
            tape_cmd = Tape.move_right,
            grid_cmd = Grid.move_right,
        ),

    '?': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.push(getinput()),
            deque_cmd = lambda deque: deque.append(getinput()),
            tape_cmd = lambda tape: tape.write_cell(ord(getchar())),
            grid_cmd = lambda grid: grid.write_cell(ord(getchar())),
        ),

    'O': overload(
            all_cmd = lambda model: print(end = str(current_value(model))),
        ),

    'Z': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.push(stack.pop() > 0),
        ),

    'R': overload(
            stack_cmd = reverse,
        ),

    '^': overload(
            grid_cmd = Grid.move_up,
        ),

    'h': overload(
            all_cmd = print,
        ),

    'o': overload(
            all_cmd = lambda model: print(end = chr(current_value(model))),
        ),

    'r': overload(
            stack_cmd = rotate,
            deque_cmd = lambda deque: deque.rotate(deque.pop()),
        ),

    's': overload(
            stack_cmd = swap,
            deque_cmd = swap,
        ),

    'Π': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.push(product(stack)),
            tape_cmd = lambda tape: tape.write_cell(product(tape)),
            grid_cmd = lambda grid: grid.write_cell(product(flatten(list(grid)))),
        ),

    'Σ': overload(
            stack_cmd = lambda stack: stack.push(sum(stack)),
            tape_cmd = lambda tape: tape.write_cell(sum(tape)),
            grid_cmd = lambda grid: grid.write_cell(sum(flatten(list(grid)))),
        ),

    '×': overload(
            stack_cmd = multiply,
            grid_cmd = lambda grid: grid.write_cell(grid.pointer_value),
        ),

    '÷': overload(
            stack_cmd = divide,
            grid_cmd = Grid.write_pointer,
        ),

}

operators = {

    '[': while_loop,
    '{': if_statement,

}

def decode(bytestring):
    decoded = ''
    continue_byte = False

    for index, byte in enumerate(bytestring):
        if continue_byte:
            continue_byte = False
            continue

        if byte == 0xff:
            continue_byte = True
            byte += bytestring[index + 1] + 1

        try:
            decoded += code_page[byte]
        except:
            raise UnicodeDecodeError('Unknown byte value: {}'.format(byte))

    return decoded

def next_index(string, start, char):
    index = start
    depth = 1
    while depth and index < len(string) - 1:
        index += 1
        if string[index] in operators.keys():
            depth += 1
        if string[index] == char:
            depth -= 1
    return index

def parse(code):
    tokens = []
    index = 0
    comment = False

    while index < len(code):
        char = code[index]

        if char == '◊':
            comment = not comment

        if comment:
            index += 1
            continue

        if char.isdigit() or char == '_':
            tokens.append(char)
            index += 1
            if index < len(code):
                char = code[index]
            while char.isdigit() and index < len(code):
                tokens[-1] += char
                index += 1
                char = code[index]
            tokens[-1] = tokens[-1].replace('_', '-')

        if char in operators.keys():
            ret = next_index(code, index, ']')
            tokens.append(operators[char](code[index + 1 : ret]))
            index = ret
        else:
            tokens.append(char)

        index += 1
    return tokens

def interpret(code, memory = None, used = None):
    tokens = parse(code)
    operable = (memory is not None)
    if used is None:
        used = []

    for tkn in tokens:

        if callable(tkn) and operable:
            tkn(memory, used)

        elif tkn in '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉' and operable:
            tkn = int(tkn.translate(digits))
            memory = used[tkn]

        elif tkn.isdigit() or (tkn[0] in '-' and tkn[1:].isdigit()):
            make_nilad(tkn, memory)

        elif tkn in memories.keys():
            arity, mem_type = memories[tkn]

            memory = mem_type(*[current_value(memory) for _ in range(arity)])
            used.append(memory)

            operable = True

        elif tkn == '@' and operable:
            used.append(memory)
            memory = used.pop(-2)

        elif tkn in functions.keys() and operable:
            functions[tkn](memory)

        else:
            continue

    return memory

if __name__ == '__main__':

    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    a = 'store_true'

    getcode = argparser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    getcode.add_argument('-f', '--file', help = 'Specifies that code be read from a file', action = a)
    getcode.add_argument('-c', '--cmd', '--cmdline', help = 'Specifies that code be read from the command line', action = a)

    argparser.add_argument('-u', '--unicode', help = 'Use utf-8 encoding for files', action = a)

    argparser.add_argument('program')
    argparser.add_argument('argv', nargs = '*')

    settings = argparser.parse_args()

    if settings.file:
        with open(settings.program, mode = 'rb') as file:
            contents = file.read()

        if settings.unicode:
            contents = ''.join([char for char in contents.decode('utf-8') if char in code_page])
        else:
            contents = decode(contents)

    if settings.cmd:
        contents = bytes(settings.program, 'utf-8')

        if settings.unicode:
            contents = ''.join([char for char in contents.decode('utf-8') if char in code_page])
        else:
            contents = decode(contents)

    interpret(contents)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Txpd9tGkt/5K5DNZEHYFCNlktlZTuTJbDLJzu5mMptjj1E0HFiEJMQkyAFBWxyv94n0RdnOZcfxlfg@Esd3fEjykfcIQonzAYJ@AvFHvF19AI2LhzzzYfet3rMJdNfVVdXdVdVNVurGbFn76ZMnaqlS1g1B1mcqsl5VUvR9qlwsKlOGWtaqrKlar6ZSzwrj4@PCq6jZkDWjit@eTaVUbVoYF6aLZdlIi@hFlFKarPlN6AU1pQrqjApIQtXQsyV5i2LoslZNi27jRnupfav9rdu47TbuuI27buOe21h0G0tuc95tNtxm023udJu73OZut7nHbe51my23uSBmBHF07IWfvvjSz/7u53/vPwGzqXJByVfkGUVADEVRNOfNhtk0d5l7zJ3m7s58Z9f7xvtaZ0/ngLm385H5idkyF8x95v7Owc7nneOdo@YB80PzI/PjzuXOtc5S5yEiwdHciGkKz/zNsz957m/FtLRhY2Yk@7wvQe4XL49v@uUrv/qHV1/79etv/ONv/umf/@XN3771u399@5133/u3f/@P//z9xPuTf8j/Ud48VVCmZ2bVD7YUS1q58ie9atS2bpur/3n7f@347/bdOKZWw9pp7TU/tfaZB81D5mfm59ZB87B51DpgfWYdtY5bp63z1kXzmHncPGF@YV2zLlu3zS@tu9aitWQ9tO6bp80z5lnzvHnRPGde6DQ6uzt7Ox@alzofmzfMr8yvzcvmN51DnSOdE51j5hXzqnnNvN75pnO9s9x5ZDWtXVbLvGntN2@Z35q3zbvWIXPR@tC8Yx22jpmnrBPWGeuCdclcMpfN@@YD67r1jXXHfGjdM7@zlq1H1gP3yL64Qdmf2nvsg/Yh@zP7sN2yP7eP2Av2UfuYvc8@bp@wv7C/tE/ap@wD9mn7jH3OPm9fsD@yL9qX7K/sr@2PgWKU5E37in3L/ta@bd@xr9p37Xv2NXvRXrKv25/Yy/Z9@4H90H5kf7d6YHV@dedqc3XX6u7VD@0bq3tW9662VhdWP4oT9Pvb3cUb3cVH3aXPusvN7@90F292F7/rLh3uLu/sLja7iyc7p7uLZ7tL8z9c6y593l063V263F3e111E3ac6Z7qL57pLjR@ud5eOdJfOdJe@6S7vb1/qNDsnO1esj6wrndudnZ1TnavWx9bVzp325fayO7/kzi/HybLSWNm7sm/l05VDK0fdm9dWvlw5v3Jl5dYP5x8fWmk9PrJy8PHpxxdXjj2@@fjWyoUfTz9@8GNz5eqP@3@40P66fa1z84d7cUSdBWefc9g57Zx1jjjnnKPOSeeU85XziXPG@cw57xxyLjgt57hzwrnk7Hd2Ox87F52DzqfOl84XTtP5fO3Y2nHnztr8WtO5t7bTWXQeOd@ttZwbaw3n9tou59u13WtHnWXn/tretRNrh9dOre1xbjk3nYfOg7WDzl3zpPkoTiZ3/rTbarqtPe5Cy11Az8fdVsttLbitA25rv9v62m1dbl9xW5fc1lfuvsPt827zYftC@1z7rNu84ja/dudvtL9rn3Ebe91Gy51/4DYW3PmH7uJRd/5i@4Y7f9ad/9Kd/8KdP@nOH3Pnj7oL59vftO@177sLF7q397qtk@2L5pFey1Rj2W3cdxuI8kO38ci813vdcpv73OZ@t3nAbX7oNrGf0aX1TaVU1utCCSmg6C2vU0W5WhXehLZcSkB/aM0Q1GrekCtKuqoUpyXSDH@6YtR0TYDWbD6PMfN59KTJJSWfRxQF8V2EhhhyhNBqPrVlHZTeAbwgqRldLayD0hsILUhIV2bUqqHo6yD2NkUNEiwof6qtR12vAZ7IrICHnMa2kHxj5POqphr5PCafETZslYs1pcrxwQywmtFuVETSpSmIL2KlVp1NxJ8u6wJuFFSNPFT9ziCDrFypKFqBMODplyuUvKoVlDkkx8hYgiYIHUDAoDwRRdkyFJUJAvacUFS0tN8sTaY45elKRafKi9IiXpbevkMSs0gNJRRQcHR4MiisSKSC@pLQVOQqiXgqc8EYxBnFQN0lz@xEWX2VERh6NY5Ghpg41n8oDaR4DMP8EiZ1P7esqn9WEB4K0DLCNl2uoOd39Rg2BAw@gh0UBz6CHbAQoY6J0clgO3ORUa9ZnSZSPIPFiHFhn5SwgYjQ10@Api93DGHmSFhHEwJa9IVJiS4OeHKpmlwUxhmAGJh1KjYGTDtFq5UUXTbIIoIllYKMtmIy4GroSQp0ISFVEM7XSxDVlwO2vO2isBFT2yiIO8QAINoXlB6oCCkVT1MQU9FG0ENITbiz77Tqq3QE4E35GFXBH/L7ShHpE1RPzLJ9B7GOmDBAiAaiXUNaaQBrDWO1oazX24p9rdnTqiE7Mu2yRRPjTORGxial1AAexSbNRNgiUXDPNhNBYdZjmD5GGdQgAxsj2RA9jZBoAKYL/IlWbF2tpCXgPdl/og24EWHNEbxXKnq5ouhG3aMypRSLvYIcQJ7wtcftRdt0xCLv4SfsQWF8fx9idErlrUpeV2dmjbAc3J6ANDcWv5Y8E7@WeBtQ1Fgc2efGfUo9HHbbrFpUeLxN430XK6@PxVejUmjMRWW615BH1j1kQdYKPKWXhdGeWuCUIIxwTIkyEGWtbAxJXZfVqiL8BgB@retlPdVDu0z0fsJiZapaFflvejQjjEq9xzTKQh3IFfqFOnPInCzUqXPPc1zcg3p6REGUAnwEOyi5eqSD0Z6LBkiMUT3aNRcNkghKQjskWBAghUKtSlnVYPkgSQLWFmcPPJgEN6sn9bElPA@rty5rM0oaYBN2U084Nj9ICAecpQG2m4HQY33tryj/IIKHOIyNDqefsVGpf4TLBT@RFYT4aY8VpJ4EENy68TaP/r2vCe7@a/jf5OCRZ2JgVlQ1nLN6w8/1DWjQbgn7P2BKwvuJQRL@yyKFFeUpJS1moBgsDoEwMSzCJEVAmzlRVI8odQJGQSKuMQi5QhFA8qI5oLWAfFoEI4nIidDUT3v7FygZfBe1v/j8SxKWN1bW/7PWSbaMN4QhdPf/s2B4PSfPgPVlm7Kuy3VWOSvJlXRRLm0uyIKc85sQYkaQJSnja1nyF/CSPJfXy9tQkKbNGLOIFGoglBQtQ@hLXF6EUxdSikFYwfSFAMdFlOBHCFxCQU@QX0xAVd7GNgJxVAxuNJiBX@dBoL5gFbngCc8PAPkqyCyDqERApPCxVA//BHA6NoyQi@RuSlEpKZqBN7fytlxM7kT6x9lTVv@ghqyBZJSSJyCFTahS8D7Fuwi4z8uboECA/w@WAueoqbjAadgKH07UplG@bPBrgQRh6bpzLbyacDJNTnDSDp159aYWzcMIVRoXxuYl4ZgRN4IYAydzcz2yucTAJH40XFrVf5ec65EJzgVTQRzAD5iozfXI1Ljh@BnTXEKOkzDExGQnKRPooQGPMydNf61wSkGpoby5yk8gKZopxvHyssch@cF6FDREobxNizVEvYdf1fsFvHO9EoKEMNxDXG@uMojX1nvoqx702nrUa2uVXqoa6aMq30vqg/ns3EA@Wx/GZ@sxPjuATjiV8D5b7@mz9QSfHZIf9llSdmCniqT0ACc1RnL9gS2pvy1rkYWc9YXW637HYB7/yElY@KRvwJMwhkaGh4852di4@z9ZfG4aGGmSnFDhqNbQHpmWsh6UNPFSbjIyGHKoitSLoAYWPEr6ZxBZEnw4PkX8I5LTOZpK4R27puso9iA7XrrE1ZDUaXLonmXn6pKAIiCvCR9rR0Ui/XjLDBMhZ@pBKuQIOokMnLdKETreOXgSGnEjrvl1Gc1AMl61gEarGvU0H1FQMOp@AIaWF71YlgtpLHR@qgQxJsPNCKCPSCNoJNyYCp0gEMkjqFgNkVa5WKRtdNL4h/eahsbPW4sqiaGoVTzBAS/25I/CURKBGkrYXrH4nlp6UiBuE0uAabAnftjHOHym7J74cZ7C0eDNEaFDYTzLBABYoAxmIA4Dl/fymlqU6TWDjMBbhy1wCnoIXEMYcpKRDi46TqIVsR2dUHCjIgknMhdJT8zliX465qahv6qT6zyv1zSyFrGrPKiZXCERXi2XSmhnguuQzxKlygU6ASltegsDXwvxLmRIuC7gvUkEtVrbbOjylDEI/kgMfqlWNNRKsT4I/oYY/IK6FU3kQbCfj@NeLtSK5UGwn4sb@zaUBPM5OUmfR16YzLDHMUiPvOeMD0Eo6Apa/6pB8ZHRZ@UqSgd1JgDcfEH5oMjSSZHf12PFnciR09ZoVESA2H0g7o2gELFQvlmoIZvyYzPKBs7jSawXStJDaTyB3RDMuNmCBH2EDUt6eTbQ5h8yIF0Y9QorfEBACUWX4OUkuMSSVEoAYhvHPUYAGqcU6Gfzj7DiJYZeanCcq2MItDfpaokJTWscVOrAlamQWGhEpAulCUABliGMHnOwHbcksHoUPVPHNguJ8FeXga@O8G6jI9MaQWeWPSfzY4zNMW1TMW2ca8soMMwImyWyjMFlGTSd4TQuZjFTtSkdex1ZufEGiCsq1I/ZO7@8@43wCrE3W16UpyY24hEjMHhHZcURjhbGCBRGCNaMYkzNyt66j5QPuqpX0bQtqFpWV9BWOOZFb6g7Eq2hD95uU7M6PkKmxFWtUjMYdUPn/QR6DAUHSwSIzJ25KaUS5UILfAEKtAtvx4xaTyIMiG1jb1Wg8lnWvW0M6xFKnvliGXkK3NflMgTSw0VtGaFWVQrceknKpcnReGBrxQNH5qgg6TArGm1QqrxSOc7UDachODCw84TFRH29ZITFKZ8BqPjCs0wmHSRLBYU8Z6uVomqkxR1iBrkbV31Wp9c1WMQ7ZqzxSXYUmw4gSVds@P63OvAcFpBFt9QqnqlLcCNZVWBqbycLj/ismBOgIAArgESCfvEntA0HN6zxDdr4Bi6lkrbXaBvOAFnjO9A4lvFybNROOsx56HkhI1C9w50GcnkxR648@g0SI2Y2KDUOJwLNTv09pOZgSDi58rF2BbE4wbjLkpI3nO9vA/yLHvwcLt7X8f@4mkbvJOTIJYekbkxwRyo17YeXnnE2Ig5ePhcs2HDJHYo1g9kan5NFOvkEMLCuB8H4lDABzNPEyEBisrg2WdZ4CE7g4N6RKHASmCfwcwMJTELZZHHD/R753EDkmXNCUy4m6sQxqpTMnuLjppzA10fS@AXCYylGul@sXzoIJIYTKAaFsyfFgJYc/p/f9EelRANTPHz4KoSDhdG4Qb@cOGhOHJjrWe9UIZE7TOc4MI/Z@F/E/jhJGg8EcdIAMkEdPkamTcMpAB8TDcAtBOex@@XTqcAPotY3ARLxB3W@so6JkDBRWqcnJhLx1PRWopr8Chplgbf@HEok4ZIDGiO9WRsXisSy@v1fzik3CbFz7O2BONAEPQb/D4n4sa5Xq8TQmB1AoViFMbjlpzIG5AADG0MfTFU4@xtuAtCMkVt94/hXB9uxt8mVHrt1oNcjbZ9@OkdjlRKS865z@jIi@P7vOmcvo8FKHThtIDdRYnVqn3vKGVYrPd2ggcDTDBjwBx2seWSwEIrWItcnUDR/jxXl3kCikLJm7y0tcM0iyApF6GU/c/Yi9AnE20@eaSaxHTXyySpBp8UPtCikN9cNBSpf2oyXwkJ7wb/UM1XW0A6G5hqAslTFr0PROzK4M3CfKUKZZaw8vWCyGc8qDiJwVEGgx4XRuenp3gQhNwsA4PaN44IvLP1m4UYB3y0b8xkFah@8pjaOC943iyeAkH8uGS6E@Hfe39NUQHoN08B339Pie9oWDYVMRCjsZDn@ThI0S8EqHRWBWFRT5ow8lj5NhpIBr9ONjADbPitAs7No6KEGr@Cba6T2S0oopA3Sdnbeje8yEmtC0YuvI8VeqeB0OQl@4XlsdotSr4bPkgi/3kTGx/E44hC9WwpeoQlh0Go3/P4EX6IxylsUnNmyKnTgpsFUuUTvnnFuTnTCa4Kjh7GQXALxgsB3MZnH4240oeBXCsIOyvjBSSN9CyKTttDVh6jSE2cHcM@qVfwrGeRkzJMnH5KG6IZFrthrBmEL355KVk4PJUWvOoaEDXtgAmkiNz6Q2Ui8JPoNr3jRBxCMIz7OvfhXV/NwdXVElKI27@v3pN7LTVxSh6RrqjgZusEZtI9HegKYTab9AcDCJeSA@qQUZ8Fxr2ocX/SL84OkCe@d/AAKK9KHyqrk1wfICTwpGQbvsHhzkputuAMPcXMRlu40pcIdynt1cUwRdQRP6ikf/tDE2AKLA@WXCxoMRdbAKo1giOMx5iHdbNGoKKz4mQpcE6IsxD4/MdObAym4gihZ/GM2RRxI49@5CRnU0y3IMoEQJqPyBGc/UIXbaSDkCJEDWsZykz5cuITsn8sjUGbQhJGzym6sw8s6vpSBYPJw9gdxGQUPyR4YGwNPb5gI5TVEkPC3ZTAXKfQ9G1AQc@nIAELOhuOE6OhgzXyll@nieCRaC@dEIy8kqNErwlI99uDqgWIdpmOsU00ItALBBMFLpVS4McX9UkU@X5JVLQ@bBT2lJL/qpOPTb/Kc/ZU@U4N96ne4J80ONCGMrKI1Sskbeo39PAgUItAU59D1rFwo5Es1o4ZmYT2PwqZirapuhfO0co0dGVI0DCpTdmlxZBovvyPTaPtAT7NKEerj4jsVZUqdhgMGY1Y28OIubFYEOFATpvVyCYlGMWSsOxCmJ5spwgaF6N4DfIliGJbGrIK3c3wcQnB55kHlhvnXCNsaiRs5tu@haLJmTI/8HMXeqAtFTHg6wOiqw3BASeaMLpfolpMEhZ62Iqoa@oQFW9zA9r2qYiCXwo0@Lv4A7Grav/XCILMgInd4p6JIDjk4XN2lAFQkctgE3PTNIpoIVSGIyTxawb8dhjvJyakU@l4bJUt1mEhAFLMfoMQrjfdVrEy2mzOgLM2eRKx4JBO343u5QM/Luxw7Sou1xCgK@RoXbPqYOGuJURcT63/z8LkYgnY8efJyvVzTyTEycn9d2fTEm4dPvKlBofD0w0D/Aw)

For those interested, the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/bugle/tree/54717f62b0790683ab7ddeb61bea02ad5f460b72) contains 18 examples, all responses to the challenges listed in the question linked in the second paragraph

Comment: If I understand correctly, at least one of file or cmd CLI argument is required. Am I right ? I am experiencing issue trying to run a simple example from your Github project.

Comment: @Josay Correct. In order to read and run a file, you must provide the `--file/-f` flag followed by the filename, and the same with the `--cmdline/-c` flag for CLI

Answer (score 6):

**Object programming**

Y'ouve split your code into various classes. Yet, it seems like the way you use them could be improved.

Indeed, the various "is_*SOMETHING*" method are very suspicious, both in the fact that it exists and the way it is implemented.

The implementation relies on the name of the class. This is fragile but also wrong if you actually plan to use inheritance. You could have an instance of a subclass of "Deque": its class would not be called "Deque" but it would actually *be* a Deque.

Thus, [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#isinstance) is what you should be using.
For instance:

```
def is_tape(self):
    return isinstance(self, Tape)

def is_stack(self):
    return isinstance(self, Stack)

def is_grid(self):
    return isinstance(self, Grid)

def is_register(self):
    return isinstance(self, Register)

def is_deque(self):
    return isinstance(self, Deque)
```

This is better but as I said previously, even having these methods in a first place seems to be against the basic principle of object programming.

You should not need to care about the type of an object, the behavior of the object itself should be defined properly. For instance, instead of having a `current_value` function checking the model class, you could have a abstract method, overriden in each subclass to have the behavior you need. This applies to `make_nilad`.

This needs quite a lot of changes, at this stage, the code looks like http://termbin.com/q8jc .

Then, the same principle applies to `overload` but it is trickier - work in progress in http://termbin.com/7x7cd .

**Index out of bound error**

I had a feeling that the boundary check in ithe `while char.isdigit()...` loop was weird and indeed, giving an input ending with 2 (or more) digits, en end up going too far in the input and throwing an exception.

I guess a better (but far from perfect) solution would be:

```
def parse(code):
    tokens = []
    index = 0
    comment = False

    while index < len(code):
        char = code[index]
        if char == '◊':
            comment = not comment
        elif not comment:
            if char in operators.keys():
                ret = next_index(code, index, ']')
                token = operators[char](code[index + 1 : ret])
                index = ret
            elif char.isdigit() or char == '_':
                #######################################
                token = char.replace('_', '-')
                index += 1
                while index < len(code):
                    char = code[index]
                    if not char.isdigit():
                        break
                    token += char
                    index += 1
                #######################################
            else:
                token = char
            tokens.append(token)

        index += 1
    return tokens
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of code here, so I'm going to go through it very sketchily. If you need a point explaining in more detail, ask.

1. There's no documentation. What is the specification of the language being interpreted? The idea of the challenge to extend and modify the language and its interpreter. The documentation will need to be extended and modified at the same time. How is this going to be done?
2. There are no docstrings. How are people supposed to modify this code if there's no specification for what the classes mean and the methods do?
3. PEP8 recommends `UPPER_CASE` for module-level constants.
4. Instead of `digits`, use [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).
5. Python concatenates adjacent string constants, so you can create `code_page` without the need for `+=`.
6. `code_page[32:128]` looks as if it is supposed to be the same as the corresponding code points in ASCII so why not make use of that fact and avoid the risk of typos?
7. There ought to be an `encode` function to correspond to `decode` otherwise how are people going to write their programs? Better still, make it a codec so that it can be passed to `open`.
8. What is the purpose of the `Model` class? It doesn't provide any common behaviour.
9. The design doesn't make use of object orientation. Consider a function like:

   ```
   def current_value(model):
       if model.is_tape() or model.is_grid():
           return model.cell
       if model.is_stack() or model.is_deque():
           return model.pop()
       if model.is_register():
           return model.value
       return False
   ```

   In an object-oriented program this function would be a method on the `Model` class and its subclasses. In the `Model` class this would be an abstract implementation:

   ```
   @abstractmethod
   @property
   def current_value(self):
       """Docstring here."""
   ```

   and then the various subclasses would override this method with concrete implementations.
10. It seems wrong for `current_value` to modify the model in some cases (stack and deque) but not in others (tape, grid and register).
11. The `Stack` model seems to be a fairly thin wrapper around a list, so it could be implemented more simply by inheriting from `list` (as the `Deque` model inherits from `collections.deque`).
12. The `Register` model inherits from `int` but does not make use of this fact. Instead it uses a superfluous attribute `value`.
13. What is a "nilad"? Google says that it is like a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad), but taking no arguments. This does not seem to correspond to anything in the `make_nilad` function. Could you choose a better name?
14. Commands that operate on a `Stack` object (`add`, `subtract` etc.) ought to be methods on the `Stack` class. Similarly for tape and grid commands.
15. The arguments to the `overload` function all end with `_cmd`; this shared suffix is unnecessary.
16. I think it would be clearer if the `Model` subclasses did their own command dispatch, instead of doing this via the `functions` mapping and the `overload` function.
17. Input is delivered to the model via `getinput` and `getchar`, which read from standard input. This makes it difficult to write unit tests because you have to make a file or a pipe in order to deliver the input for the test case. It would be better to take input in some other way, for example from an buffer object passed to `interpret`.
18. There are lots of opportunities for η-conversion. For example `lambda size, wrap: Tape(size, wrap)` could be just `Tape` and `lambda xlen, ylen, xwrap, ywrap: Grid(xlen, ylen, xwrap, ywrap)` could be just `Grid`.
19. It seems strange that an if expression starts with `{` but ends with `]`. I would have expected it to end with `}`.
20. `next_index` goes wrong if `]` appears in a comment. (Maybe `]` is not allowed to appear in a comment but if so I think this would need to be checked in `parse`.)
21. `while_loop` re-parses the body of the loop each time round the loop. Is this deliberate? This seems like a waste of time compared to the normal approach of parsing just once.
22. I recommend splitting up the tasks of tokenization, parsing and interpretation, instead of mixing them as here. ([See](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15450/11728) [these](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/145608/11728) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160588/11728).)
23. There are no unit tests.

Comment: I got the term `nilad` from [this](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) golfing language I use. However, when I googled "nilad", all the results were relating to a plant. What did you search?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `η-conversion`? I'm not familiar with the term

Comment: [η-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) is a term from the λ-calculus — it refers to the operation that transforms \$λx.yx\$ into \$y\$.